# install an tar.gz autotools project on windows

Tags: c, windows, autotools

So I have [this tar.gz Project,](http://ruby.chemie.uni-freiburg.de/~martin/hp2xx-3.5.0a35.tar.gz) which is hp2xx , a hpgl converter. I need to use it for a project. But i dont know, how to install it, given the fact that this is an unbuilt project, so i need to do it myself.

I know it has been created with Autotools, but i seriously dont know how to use that information to install it on windows.

Whats the best way to install it on Windows?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Have you unpacked that tar file and read all of the available documentation?  Did you build it?  Did the build generate and installer?  It might be all you have to do is add it to your path or run something.

Comment: Unpack it (`tar xzfv hp2xx-3.5.0a35.tar.gz`), enter the  'makes' directory and use on of the one and a half dozen make- and project files to build the binaries.

Comment: It isn't an Autotools project. Just plain `make`.